# Changed project from xampp folder to another folder and deleted previous xampp version

Tags: php, laravel

Changed a working project folder to another folder and I have given permission too but now it won't work
also it shows following error when I login.

```
file_put_contents(D:\Videos\htdocs\salesapp\storage\framework\views/34f87b7f19f81a3c49159deded5ed0b821a7e81d.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what was the old location? what is the new location?

Comment: how did you change the working project folder to another folder?

Comment: this looks like the laravel blade file caching problem. You should clear the cache of the blade by using ` php artisan view:clear`  or copy the files from previous projects framework folder too (not sure copying works)

Comment: i guess no one knows what `file_put_contents` is for :p

Comment: @lagbox isn't file_put_contents is trying to fetch the compiled blade cached file in this scenario? I also had similar issue sometimes ago and for me just clearing cache file worked :)

Comment: @AnujShrestha no it is for writing to a file

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Use this and it will remove temp files you have moved app folder by temp files are missing.

also try clearing view cache before you move.

Comment: `cache:clear` is for the cache store ... if you are using redis it would clear your redis store... this isn't for the config cache or view cache or route cache

Comment: Please check the error its has specifically mentions `views` folder

Comment: it was a typo i wrote cache instead of view

Comment: actually i installed xampp labelled as videos in E drive where my whole project stored. later i uninstall it and reinstall to d drive labelled as xampp.since i have faced the issue

Answer (score 0):

just delete all temp files from following folders.

```
1. storage/framework/views/
2. storage/framework/sessions/
3. storage/framework/cache/data/
```

Answer (score -1):

=> Try this method:

Goto the **bootstrap/cache** and rename/remove the **config.php** file.

After this you can run this command:

`php artisan cache:clear` **OR**

`php artisan config:cache` (when you deploy on server)

> If you execute the **config:cache** command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the **env** function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the **.env** file will not be loaded and all calls to the **env** function will return **null**.

I hope it would helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: there is no reason to cache the configuration while in development, btw

Comment: basically `config:cache` command first clear your application cache then cache the configuration.

Comment: and again, there is no reason to cache the configuration for local development, if you want to clear the cached config, you just clear the cached config, you dont need to recache it

Answer (score -1):

If you have cached your configuration (which there is no need to do in development) you will need to remove the cached configuration. The cached configuration includes a configuration value for where the compiled view files should be placed.

You can clear the cached configuration via the command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

There is no reason to run `config:cache`, caching the configuration, while in development.

If you can not run this command you can check in `bootstrap/cache` for a `config.php` file and delete it.

> "You should typically run the `php artisan config:cache` command as part of your **production** deployment routine. The command should **not** be run during **local** development as configuration options will frequently need to be changed during the course of your application's development."

**Side Note:** Since this comes up constantly, `cache:clear` has nothing to do with the configuration cache, the view cache or the route cache, it is for clearing your cache store and the cache for the real time facades only.